# How to initialize main window objects from custom class during program start?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a main window with a couple of popupbuttons. I want to clear them, then load the lists from a method in a custom class. I've got my view controller working and I know the method in the custom class (newRequest) is working because I added a NSLog command to print "Test" when the method executes. In AppDelegate I'm calling the method via:
[polyAppRequest newRequest];.
As I said, I know the method is executing. Why can't I removeallitems from the popupbutton from this custom class method?
Thanks
Keith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that you should use an NSWindowController to manage a window. See here:

[Windows and window controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9hwY.png)

[Adding views or windows to MainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511619/adding-views-or-windows-to-mainwindow)

Then if your window gets complicated enough, the NSWindowController can employ various NSViewControllers to manage parts of the window.

In any case, I used an NSWindowController in my answer.

The image below shows the outlet's for File's Owner, which is my `MainWindowController`:

[image]

I created MainWindowController .h/.m in `Xcode6.2` by:

1. Selecting File>New>File>OS X - Source - Cocoa Class
2. Selecting NSWindowController for `Subclass of:`
3. Checking `also create .xib file for user interface`

Then I deleted the window--not the menu--in the default MainMenu.xib, and I changed the name of MainWindowController.xib, created by the steps above, to MainWindow.xib.

The following code works for me (but I'm a Cocoa beginner!):

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  PopUpButtons

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainWindowController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property(strong) MainWindowController* mainWindowCtrl;

@end


@implementation AppDelegate


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    [self setMainWindowCtrl:[[MainWindowController alloc] init]];
    [[self mainWindowCtrl] showWindow:nil];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

...

```
//
//  MainWindowController.m
//  PopUpButtons
//

#import "MainWindowController.h"
#import "MyData.h"

@interface MainWindowController ()

@property(strong) MyData* data;
@property(weak) IBOutlet NSPopUpButton* namePopUp;
@property(weak) IBOutlet NSPopUpButton* agePopUp;

@end


@implementation MainWindowController

-(id)init {

    if (self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindow"]) {
        _data = [[MyData alloc] init];  //Get data for popups
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.

    [[self namePopUp] removeAllItems];
    [[self namePopUp] addItemsWithTitles:[[self data] drinks]];
    [[self agePopUp] removeAllItems];
    [[self agePopUp] addItemsWithTitles:[[self data] extras]];
}

@end
```

...

```
//
//  MyData.h
//  PopUpButtons
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyData : NSObject

@property NSArray* drinks;
@property NSArray* extras;

@end
```

...

```
//
//  MyData.m
//  PopUpButtons
//

#import "MyData.h"

@implementation MyData

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _drinks = @[@"coffee", @"tea"];
        _extras = @[@"milk", @"sugar", @"honey"];
    }

    return self;

}

@end
```

I hope that helps.  If you need any more screenshots, let me know.

**Edit1:**

I think I see what you are asking about.  Although I don't think it is a very good approach, if I change my code to this:

```
//
//  MyData.h
//  PopUpButtons
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyData : NSObject

@property (copy) NSArray* drinks;
@property (copy) NSArray* extras;

-(void)newRequest;

@end
```

...

```
//
//  MyData.m
//  PopUpButtons
//

#import "MyData.h"

@interface MyData()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSPopUpButton* drinksPopUp;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSPopUpButton* extrasPopUp;

@end


@implementation MyData

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _drinks = @[@"coffee", @"tea"];
        _extras = @[@"milk", @"sugar", @"honey"];
    }

    return self;

}


-(void)newRequest {
    [[self drinksPopUp] removeAllItems];
    [[self drinksPopUp] addItemsWithTitles:[self drinks]];

    [[self extrasPopUp] removeAllItems];
    [[self extrasPopUp] addItemsWithTitles:[self extras]];
}

@end
```

I am unable to populate the NSPopUpButtons. This is what I did:

1. I dragged an Object from the Object Library to the dock in IB, and in the Identity Inspector, I changed the Object's class to MyData.
2. Then I clicked on the Connections Inspector, and the two instance variables in MyData, drinksPopUp and extrasPopUp, were listed in the Outlets.
3. I dragged from the outlets to the respective NSPopUpButtons.

I guess I assumed, like you, that when my program ran, the NSPopUpButtons would be assigned to the instance variables drinksPopUp and extrasPopUp--but that doesn't seem to be the case.  According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html), you should be able to do that:

> An application typically sets outlet connections between its custom
>   controller objects and objects on the user interface, but they can be
>   made between any objects that can be represented as instances in
>   Interface Builder,...

**Edit2:**

I am able to pass the NSPopUpButtons from my MainWindowController to the newRequest method, and I can use the NSPopUpButtons inside newRequest to successfully populate the data.

**Edit3:**

> I know the method in the custom class (newRequest) is working because
>   I added a NSLog command to print "Test" when the method executes.

But what happens when you log the variables that point to the NSPopUpButtons?  With my code in `Edit1`, I get NULL for the variables, which means the NSPopUpButtons never got assigned to the variables.

**Edit4**:

If I add an `awakeFromNib` method to MyData, and inside awakeFromNib I log the NSPopUpButton variables for the code in Edit1, I get non NULL values.  That tells me that the MainWindowController's windowDidLoad method is executing before MyData's awakeFromNib method, and therefore you cannot call newRequest inside MainWindowController's windowDidLoad method because MyData has not been fully initialized.

**Edit5**:

Okay, I got the code in Edit1 to work.  The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html) say this:

> About the Top-Level Objects
>
> When your program loads a nib file, Cocoa recreates the entire graph
>   of objects you created in Xcode. This object graph includes all of the
>   windows, views, controls, cells, menus, and custom objects found in
>   the nib file. The top-level objects are the subset of these objects
>   that do not have a parent object [in IB]. The top-level objects typically
>   include only the windows, menubars, and custom controller objects that
>   you add to the nib file [like the MyData Object]. (Objects such as File’s Owner, First
>   Responder, and Application are placeholder objects and not considered
>   top-level objects.)
>
> **Typically, you use outlets in the File’s Owner object to store
>   references to the top-level objects of a nib file.** If you do not use
>   outlets, however, you can retrieve the top-level objects from the
>   nib-loading routines directly. You should always keep a pointer to
>   these objects somewhere because your application is responsible for
>   releasing them when it is done using them. For more information about
>   the nib object behavior at load time, see Managing the Lifetimes of
>   Objects from Nib Files.

In accordance with the bolded line above, I changed this declaration in MainWindowController.m:

```
@interface MainWindowController ()

@property(strong) MyData* data;
...

@end
```

to this:

```
@interface MainWindowController ()

@property(strong) IBOutlet MyData* data;
...

@end
```

Then, in IB I dragged a connection from the MainWindowController *data* outlet to the MyData Object(the Object I had previously dragged out of the Object Library and onto the doc).

I guess that causes MyData to unarchive from the .xib file and initialize before MainWindowController.

Comment: Hi, I've ready your comments up to edit 3 (thank you for the detailed reply). I'm not passing any variable info to my method in my custom class. I assign the variables in the method and I've made the IBOutlet connections from my custom class to the main widow via the NSViewController. All I'm trying to do from the main program (AppDelegate) is to run the method and have it do all the work of updating the items in the popup button. Thanks, Keith

Comment: Hi Keith,  1) I believe the experts would consider that a poor way to organize things.  In the MVC model, the Model(your custom class) is not allowed to communicate directly with the View(the window).  Rather, the Controller should retrieve the data from the Model(your custom class), then send the data to the View.  I think my initial example(at the bottom of my answer) is the way to organize things.  However, I was still interested in figuring out why my Edit1 code(which I think is similar to your code) wouldn’t work.  In Edit4, I described what I think is happening...

Comment: which is that the your custom class instance, 
which your Controller has a pointer to, 
does not get initialized until after windowDidLoad executes. 
 In other words, the pointers to the NSPopUpButtons do not get assigned to your custom class’s instance variables until after windowDidLoad executes.  
In Edit5, there is a quote from the Apple docs, which suggests, that the window’s owner, i.e. the File’s Owner in IB(which I think is your ViewController) should have an outlet pointing to your custom class instance....

Comment: If I change the declaration of the variable in my WindowController, which points to my custom class instance, to add IBOutlet to the declaration; then drag from that outlet in the Connections Inspector to my custom class instance, the code works.  In other words, the instance variables in my custom class are assigned the NSPopUpButtons *before* windowDidLoad executes.  I think that creating a connection between the Controller and the custom class instance sort of makes the custom class instance a subObject of the Controller, which then must be initialized before the Controller's...

Comment: window can load.  But, once again, I don't think you should organize your code like that.

Comment: *All I'm trying to do from the main program (AppDelegate) is to run the method and have it do all the work of updating the items in the popup button.*   I think your AppDelegate is sort of like a WindowController--however the links I posted say that Xcode's default files are the *wrong* way to organize a project--the AppDelegate should only create a WindowController and then tell the WindowController to display its window.   In any case, if you consider your AppDelegate to be the WindowController, and your ViewController to be the WindowController's helper to get the window ready...

Comment: then your AppDelegate(WindowController) should call a method in the ViewController to populate the NSPopUpButtons.  In turn, the ViewController should retrieve the data from your custom class, then the ViewController should set the data in the PopUpButtons by calling removeAllItems, etc.